# How to figure out which objects survived n minor GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, dump

In my application I see that some objects keep coming to the old gen:

```
- age   1:   23911192 bytes,   23911192 total
- age   2:     627816 bytes,   24539008 total
- age   3:      60344 bytes,   24599352 total
- age   4:      19488 bytes,   24618840 total
- age   5:      12864 bytes,   24631704 total
- age   6:      10632 bytes,   24642336 total
- age   7:      11472 bytes,   24653808 total
- age   8:      10944 bytes,   24664752 total
- age   9:      39480 bytes,   24704232 total
- age  10:      10288 bytes,   24714520 total
- age  11:       8072 bytes,   24722592 total
- age  12:       9976 bytes,   24732568 total
- age  13:      13112 bytes,   24745680 total
- age  14:       8928 bytes,   24754608 total
- age  15:       8600 bytes,   24763208 total <-- who are these guys?
```

So, I wanted to ask what is the best way to figure out who are those objects that survived 15 minor GC?

Application works for an hour, so it's not a warm up period.

Comment: why would it matter? it's only a miniscule fraction, it's not like it's going to trigger an excessive amount of old gen collections.

Comment: @the8472, it may not matter a lot. I'm just interested what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any option that breaks down instances by tenuring age

But if we ask which objects live to the age 16 instead then that's the objects that get promoted to the old generation. Which can be traced with `-XX:+PrintClassHistogram`. Diffing the histograms after a full GC and before the next full GC will show you which objects bled into the old gen in the young collections in between.

Using a memory profiler that supports snapshots and their comparison can provide similar insight.

For java 9's unified logging the equivalent option is `-Xlog:classhisto*=trace`